# Ubuntu server folder permissions

Tags: php, ubuntu, upload, permissions

I have an uploads directory on my server, php upload works fine when folder's permission is set to 755 but if I make new dir inside uploads (uploads/subuploaddir) upload fails and I need to set 755 permission for this folder manually, so my question is how can I set 755 permission for uploads dir and all of it's future created sub directories?

PS. chmod -R 755 ...mypath/uploads    doesn't work

Thanks in advance.
All answers are very appreciated.
Peter

UPDATE:
Problem solved, my fault. PHP creates folders with permission 777 as default and I created folders for testing purposes through FTP manually, so it was created by another system user and with different permission.

Comment: PHP has it's own [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) command that you can use.

Comment: check for ownership also what it is to change ownership use chown command

Comment: Lix - Yep, I know that would be good solution but when I used shared hosting I didn't have to use that. I just created folder and it worked. (I'm newbie to Ubuntu console)

Comment: use chown instead of chmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
umask(022);
```

in PHP before creating a file (e.g. line 1 in index.php). Using that option, every files that PHP creates will have a permission that equals to 755. If that doesn't work, search your code for calls to `umask` and change them to the one above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command
chmod -R 755 directorypath or file